# Report of multiple different memberships per contact in one line

Tags: civireport

CiviCRM 4.6.8 and WP 4.3.1
Many of our members have two memberships, a main membership (ie. Professional or Student) and a State(or area) Chapter membership (ie. California or New England, etc.).   How can I report in a single line what memberships a member has?  Do I need to do this in SQL or can I do this in a native CiviReport.   If SQL could someone get me started.  THANKS.

Comment: how many membership do you have for an single contact is it always 2 membership ??

Comment: typically two but sometimes just one or it could be many.  We have 17 chapters that an individual could become a member of!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the below SQL to list all the membership related to single membership in an single row - I guess this helps

select 
GROUP_CONCAT(b.name) 
from civicrm_membership a,civicrm_membership_type b where b.id = a.membership_type_id
and a.contact_id in (select contact_id from civicrm_membership GROUP BY contact_id having COUNT(*) > 1)

Comment: I wasn't very clear.   I need to list all memberships for a Client/Contact in one row.   I need client name, membership type(s) and start/end date.  If you get me started I think I can figure out the rest.

Comment: SELECT (select display_name from civicrm_contact where id =  a.contact_id) as company_name, GROUP_CONCAT(b. NAME),GROUP_CONCAT(a.start_date),GROUP_CONCAT(a.end_date) 
FROM  civicrm_membership a,  civicrm_membership_type b
WHERE b.id = a.membership_type_id 
AND a.contact_id IN ( SELECT contact_id FROM civicrm_membership GROUP BY contact_id ) GROUP BY a.contact_id

Comment: above script will list company name, all membership type , start_date, end_date - please test the script and let me know the status - thanks

Comment: so far so good.  I just installed MySQL Workbench and ran this.  Looks good!  Greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: Where in the select would I put a where clause to grab just the Membership Status of 1,2 or 3 (New, Current, Grace)

Comment: SELECT (SELECT display_name FROM civicrm_contact WHERE id = a.contact_id ) AS company_name, GROUP_CONCAT(b. NAME), GROUP_CONCAT(a.start_date), GROUP_CONCAT(a.end_date) FROM civicrm_membership a, civicrm_membership_type b WHERE b.id = a.membership_type_id AND a.status_id IN (1,2,3) AND a.contact_id IN ( SELECT contact_id FROM civicrm_membership GROUP BY contact_id ) GROUP BY a.contact_id - I have updated the SQL

Comment: Excellent, this is a big help.  I may have another question or two but this gets me started.

Comment: please drop your question let me see what i can do

Comment: Here's a list of fields I need for the query.  Can these all be added?   First Name(already have),
Middle Name,
Last Name(already have),
Job Title,
Current Employer,
Street Address,
Supplemental Address 1,
City,
State,
Postal Code,
Phone,
Email,
Chapter Membership Type(already have),
Membership Type(already have),
Member Since Date,
Membership Expiration Date(already have),
Membership Status,
Total Amount,

Comment: I got the Middle Name and Job Title.  See previous post.... I'm not sure how to get the Current Employer, Member Since, Membership Status, and total amount.

Comment: hi Gary, I have created the SQL but it is too long for the comment so i am posting it as an answer - if you have any issues please let me know - thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
membership.id,
contact.first_name,
contact.middle_name,
contact.last_name,
contact.job_title,
contact.organization_name,
address.street_name,
address.supplemental_address_1,
(
    SELECT
        NAME
    FROM
        civicrm_state_province
    WHERE
        id = address.state_province_id
) AS state,
address.city,
address.postal_code,
phone.phone,
GROUP_CONCAT(mem_type. NAME),
GROUP_CONCAT(membership.join_date) AS since_date,
GROUP_CONCAT(membership.start_date),
GROUP_CONCAT(membership.end_date),
(
    SELECT
        NAME
    FROM
        civicrm_membership_status
    WHERE
        id = GROUP_CONCAT(membership.status_id)
) AS membership_status,

contribution.total_amount,
line_item.qty,
line_item.unit_price,
line_item.line_total,
line_item.label,
email.email
FROM
civicrm_membership membership
LEFT JOIN civicrm_membership_type mem_type ON mem_type.id = membership.membership_type_id
LEFT JOIN civicrm_contact contact ON contact.id = membership.contact_id
LEFT JOIN civicrm_address address ON address.contact_id = contact.id AND address.is_primary = 1
LEFT JOIN civicrm_phone phone ON phone.contact_id = contact.id AND phone.is_primary = 1
LEFT JOIN civicrm_membership_payment payment ON payment.membership_id = membership.id
LEFT JOIN civicrm_contribution contribution ON contribution.id = payment.contribution_id
LEFT JOIN civicrm_email email ON email.contact_id = contact.id AND email.is_primary = 1
LEFT JOIN civicrm_line_item line_item ON  line_item.entity_id = membership.id 
WHERE
membership.status_id IN (1, 2, 3)
AND membership.contact_id IN (
SELECT
    contact_id
FROM
    civicrm_membership
GROUP BY
    contact_id
)
GROUP BY
membership.contact_id
```

Comment: Excellent... this is amazing!   Is there a way to get email address?   Also, is it possible to list the items in a price in the contribution?  Some of the Contributions have a price set for the memberships.  See below:Payment Amount 
Item Qty Unit Price Total Price
Dues - Professional 1 $ 290.00 $ 290.00
Chapter Dues - New England 1 $ 35.00 $ 35.00

Comment: hi Gary, I have updated the SQL please give a test - thanks

Comment: the values in the line item are not right.... bad part is that my data is not consistent to test this.  The line items are not in every membership because some I had to import.  As new members sign up then they use the price set(line items) to purchase the membership.  I  think the line items would need to be concatenated because there could be more than one per membership.  Also when you made the change the current ConCat fields duplicated themselves. In the Mem Type.Name field, instead of "Professional, Oregon" it now has "Oregon, Professional, Oregon, Professional"

Comment: ok sorry about that but without seeing the data its bit hard to create a SQL - please remove civicrm_line_item - and i guess rest should work correctly for your requirement - let me see what i can do to list the line item

Comment: ok... I removed the line item pieces.  Working ok but not getting Total Amount from the Contribution.  I can send you sample data/screen shots.... just need a way to get them to you.

Comment: Please send me the sample data to ramesh@millertech.co.uk so i can have a look at the data and will create the SQL

Comment: sent.  Let me know if you need anything else.